# How to inject property from application.yaml to config bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have one main configuration file that is:

```
@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("main.config")
public class AerospikeCacheConfig {
    private String host;
    private int port;
    private int maxConnectionsPerEventLoop;
    private SubConfig1 subConfig1;
    private SubConfig2 subConfig2;
}
```

`SubConfig1` and `SubConfig2` have one common property which called `namespace` that's first file code:

```
@Getter
public class SubConfig1 extends Config {

    private final long refreshCounterServiceInterval;

    public SubConfig1(String namespace, int minRemoteTtl) {
        super(namespace, minRemoteTtl);
    }
```

That is second file code:

```
@Getter
public class SubConfig2 extends Config {
    private final long refreshValueServiceInterval;


    public SubConfig2(String namespace, long refreshCounterInterval) {
        super(namespace);
        this.refreshValueServiceInterval = refreshCounterInterval;
    }
```

That is `Config.class`:

```
@Getter
public class Config {
    private final int minRemoteTtl;
    private final String namespace;

    public Config(String namespace) {
        this(namespace, 1);
    }

    public Config(String namespace, int minRemoteTtl) {
        this.minRemoteTtl = minRemoteTtl;
        this.namespace = namespace;
    }
}
```

All config files from one package.
and I have application.yaml file:

```
main:
  config:
    namespace: test
    host: 127.0.0.1
    port: 10000
    maxConnectionsPerEventLoop: 100
    subConfig1:
      minRemoteTtl: 1
    subConfig2:
      refreshCounterInterval: 5
```

I need `namespace` property autowired into `SubConfig1` and `SubConfig2`. 
How can I do that?

Comment: Can you please provide either code or import package for `Config` class?

Comment: Yes, I added ```Config``` class.

Comment: you don't need constructors, and please provide `Setters and getters`, check this https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties